# Integral of a fraction

Tags: integration

The question is to find the $\int\frac{1}{x^{2}+4} dx$

When I first solved this I thought that the answer was $\frac{1}{2x} ln(x^2 +4)$

However I was told that the answer was $\frac{1}{2} tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})+c$

I dont understand how they came to this answer. Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: get the derivatives of these functions.

Comment: If i answer, surely the downvoters will do it.

Comment: Note that you'll have to apply product rule and chain rule when taking the derivative of $\frac1{2x}\ln(x^2+4)$.  Always good to take the derivative of your end answer to check your work and build intuition as to which processes went into finding the anti-derivative.

Comment: Harsh downvotes IMHO. This is a legitimate question and the source of confusion of the OP is certainly worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Factorize $x^2+4$ as $4((\frac{x}{2})^2+1)$
2. Let $u:=\frac{x}{2}$
3. Recall that $\arctan'(u) = \frac{1}{u^2+1}$
4. Use the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) to conclude

By the way, your answer is wrong because you seem to treat $x$ as a constant as well as a variable. When you make the change of variable $u:=x^2+4$, you do get $du=2x$, but that leads you to
$$
\int\frac{1}{2x}\cdot\frac{1}{u}du
$$
and you have to express $2x$ as a function of $u$ to evaluate this.

Answer (score 1):

First, take the derivative of your answer.  The product or quotient rule you use should show you your answer is wrong.

The normal way to do this integral is by trig substitution.  Let $x = 2\tan \theta$, so that $dx = 2 \sec^2 \theta \; d\theta.$  Then

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2+4} \; dx = \int \frac{1}{4\tan^2 \theta +4} 2\sec^2 \theta \; d\theta = \int \frac{2\sec^2 \theta}{4\sec^2 \theta} \; d\theta = \int \frac{1}{2} \; d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\theta+C.$$

Then note that $\theta = \arctan\frac{x}{2}. $

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is one of those things where you sort of have to know what the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ looks like (so that you can recognize it when doing the integral).

We can figure this out with implicit differentiation:
$$y=\tan^{-1}(x)\iff \tan(y)=x$$ so we can differentiate both sides and obtain $$\sec^2(y)\cdot y'=1$$ Now, we use the Pythagorean identity $$\tan^2(y)+1=\sec^2(y)$$ and obtain $$\left(\tan^2(y)+1\right)\cdot y'=1$$ We substitute in $\tan(y)=x$, and divide through to obtain $$y'=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

Thus, we have shown $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}\tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$

Other answers have shown how to use substitution or factorization to evaluate the integral given this fact.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x = 2\tan \theta$, $dx = 2 \sec^2\theta\ d\theta$, and using the identity $\sec^2 x = \tan^2 x + 1$,

$$\begin{align*}
\int\frac{dx}{x^2+4}
&= \int\frac{2\sec^2\theta\ d\theta}{4\tan^2\theta + 4}\\
&= \int\frac{2\sec^2\theta\ d\theta}{4\sec^2\theta}\\
&= \frac12\int d\theta\\
&= \frac12\theta + C\\
&= \frac12 \tan^{-1}\frac x2 + C
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x^2+4)=\frac{2x}{x^2+4}$. I think that's why you have the 'answer' $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2x}\ln(x^2+4)$.

However, as $2x$ is not a constant, we cannot just divide $\displaystyle \ln(x^2+4)$ by $2x$ to obtain the anti-derivative. Indeed, you have to use the chain rule.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{1}{2x}\ln(x^2+4)\right]=\frac{1}{2x}\cdot\frac{2x}{x^2+4}-\frac{1}{2x^2}\ln(x^2+4)\ne\frac{1}{x^2+4}$$

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ is the answer. Let $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$. Then

$$2\tan2y=x$$

So, we have

\begin{align}
\frac{d2\tan2y}{d(2y)}\frac{d(2y)}{dx}&=1\\
4\sec^22y\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
(4\tan^22y+4)\frac{2y}{dx}&=1\\
(x^2+4)\frac{dy}{dx}&=1\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{1}{x^2+4}
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: The derivative of $x \mapsto \arctan(x)$ is $x \mapsto {1 \over 1+x^2}$.

And the derivative of $x \mapsto {\ln(x^2+4) \over 2x}$ is $$x \mapsto \dfrac{\dfrac{2x}{x^2+4}2x - 2\ln(x^2+4)}{(2x)^2}=\dfrac{1}{x^2+4}-\dfrac{\ln(x^2+4)}{2x^2}$$

It seems that you forgot the '$-uv'$ part in the derivative of ${u \over v}$: $\left(\dfrac{u}{v}\right)' = \dfrac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$

Comment: Perhaps this is a hint ? ( I didn't upvote the answer though)